# Run multiprocessing and threading together

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

so first thing there is no error in the code but the problem is I thought that it would be fast but it took same time without multiprocessing So is there a way to make it faster? so I tried multiprocessing and threading together but cant see a goodd result this is a port scanner tool that I am trying to make fast  and also thanks in advance.

```
import socket
import threading
from queue import Queue
import subprocess
import sys
import os
import multiprocessing as mp


open_ports = []        
print_lock = threading.Lock()
host = sys.argv[1]

try:
    protocol = sys.argv[2]  #User Specified Protocol
except IndexError:
    protocol = '-vvv' #Default Prtocol

q = Queue()

# color class
class color:
    blue = '\033[94m'
    green = '\033[92m'
    red = '\033[93m'
    underline = '\033[4m'
    reset = '\033[0m'


# banner
def banner():
    os.system('clear')
    print(f'{color.blue}----------------------------------------------------------------')
    print(r"""
        __   ___      __ __________                
       / /  <  /___ _/ //__  / ___/_________ _____ 
      / /   / / __ `/ __ \/ /\__ \/ ___/ __ `/ __ \
     / /___/ / /_/ / / / / /___/ / /__/ /_/ / / / /
    /_____/_/\__, /_/ /_/_//____/\___/\__,_/_/ /_/ 
            /____/                                
    """)
    print('----------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('[+] You should have latest Version of NMAP installed')
    print('[+] Developed By $witch<Blade#0001')
    print(f'[+] Only supports IPv4{color.reset}')
    print(f'{color.red}[+] I am not Rusted{color.reset}')
    print(f'{color.blue}----------------------------------------------------------------\n\n{color.reset}')


def portscan(port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)        # connecting to the remote host
    s.settimeout(1)
    try:
        con = s.connect((host, port))        # scanning the ports
        with print_lock:
            print(f'{color.green}[+] port {port} is open{color.reset}')
            open_ports.append(port)
        con.close()            # closing connection
    except:
        pass

def threader():
    while True:
        worker = q.get()
        portscan(worker)
        q.task_done()

def thread1():
    for x in range(700):
        t = threading.Thread(target = threader)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    for worker in range(1, 32767):
        q.put(worker)

def thread2():
    for x in range(700):
        t = threading.Thread(target = threader)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    for worker in range(32768, 65535):
        q.put(worker)

q.join()

def muti_processing():
    p1 = mp.Process(target = thread1)
    p2 = mp.Process(target = thread2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start() 


if __name__== '__main__':
    banner()
    muti_processing()

print(f'{color.blue}\n \n ----------------------------------------------------------')
print('[+] Now All the ports are Scanned')
print(f'[+] Our Nmap Come in Action, [nmap host {protocol} -T4 -p open_ports]')
print(f'----------------------------------------------------------{color.reset}')
separator = ", "
apple = separator.join(map(str, open_ports))
print(color.green)
output = subprocess.check_output(['nmap', host, protocol, '-T4', '-p', apple])
print(output.decode('utf-8'))
print(color.reset)'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, multiprocessing is used for CPU heavy computations where multi-threading is used (often) for I/O bound tasks i.e when fetching data from a database etc.

To be honest, I don't know what your code is doing, but it seems it does a lot of non-CPU-heavy scans/stuff thus I might just stick to multi-threading

Comment: waiting on sockets is a great application for asyncio too which has less overhead than threads.

Comment: Agreed - I thought about mentioning that aswell but since he specific asked for multithreading/multiproccessing I didn't